# Python Web Scraping - How To Skip Non-Existent Elements In Iteration

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, xpath

How do I return a different value in my iterator for xpaths that don't exist?

I'm scraping a comparison site but not all elements are present across all the listings due to different offerings.

Problem breakdown:

1. I start by getting the total number of listings and storing them in the variable 'savings' and use the len(savings) value as my iteration range.

savings = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="rc-ratetable"]/div/div')))

2. There is a field that specifies offer mechanics with the xpath '//*[@id="rc-ratetable"]/div/div[{i}]/div[2]/div[2]/div[4]/p' however it is not present on all the listings because some do not have applicable offers. And so when my iterator passes through a non-existent {i}, it triggers the exception.

My current solution:
I got it to work by using try-except but it's taking too long since it has to go through all the exceptions and surely there's a better way to do this.

I've included my code below:

```
import time
import datetime
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url = 'https://www.ratecity.com.au/savings-accounts'
driver.get(url)

time.sleep(2.5)

driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 1080)")

time.sleep(2.5)

driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 2080)")

get_today = datetime.datetime.now()
today = get_today.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
affiliate = 'RateCity'
rank = 1

results = [['Date', 'Affiliate', 'Position', 'Provider', 'Product', 'Maximum Rate', 'Standard Rate', 'Max Rate Conditions', 'Savings Details']]

load_more_button = f'//*[@id="__next"]/div/main/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[4]/div[1]/div/button'
load_more_clicks = 2

for i in range(1, load_more_clicks):
    driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click();', WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, load_more_button))))
    time.sleep(2.5)
    
read_more = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="rc-ratetable"]/div/div//span[contains(text()," ...read more")]')))
for i in range(1, len(read_more) + 1):
    read_more_button = f'//*[@id="rc-ratetable"]/div/div//span[contains(text()," ...read more")]'
    driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click();', WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, read_more_button))))
    time.sleep(1.5)
    
savings = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="rc-ratetable"]/div/div')))
    
for i in range(1, len(savings) + 1) :
    
    try :
        savings_conditions = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, f'//*[@id="rc-ratetable"]/div/div[{i}]/div[2]/div[2]/div[4]/p'))).text.replace(' ...read less','')
    except :
        savings_conditions = 'No max rate conditions listed'
    
    print(savings_conditions)
```

Comment: i guess you should first handle exception first and only use those string methods in maybe second line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to point out that the reason why it is slow isn't entirely because of the exception, but more towards the conditional check of element presence, especially those without `savings_conditions`, eg, `//*[@id="rc-ratetable"]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[4]/p`, given an element conditional check is already done when retrieving `savings`, you may proceed to retrieve the `savings_conditions`
directly.

```
for i in range(1, len(savings) + 1):
    try:
        savings_conditions = driver.find_element(
            By.XPATH, f'//*[@id="rc-ratetable"]/div/div[{i}]/div[2]/div[2]/div[4]/p').text.replace(
            ' ...read less', '')
    except NoSuchElementException:
        savings_conditions = 'No max rate conditions listed'
    print(savings_conditions)
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you need to wait for those elements to become loaded you can reduce the `WebDriverWait` timeout to set it f.e. to 3 seconds instead of 30 seconds, as following.

```py
for i in range(1, len(savings) + 1) :    
    try :
        savings_conditions = WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, f'//*[@id="rc-ratetable"]/div/div[{i}]/div[2]/div[2]/div[4]/p'))).text.replace(' ...read less','')
    except :
        savings_conditions = 'No max rate conditions listed'
    
    print(savings_conditions)
```

In case you do not really need to wait there since the page is already loaded you can use simple `driver.find_elements` method (in case you did not set `implicitly_wait` in your code and you should not do that since you are using `WebDriverWait` and these two should not be mixed) since `driver.find_elements` returns a list of web element objects in any case, it does not throw exception. The list will be empty if no matches and non-empty if match found.
So, your code could be as following:

```py
for i in range(1, len(savings) + 1) :
    result = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, f'//*[@id="rc-ratetable"]/div/div[{i}]/div[2]/div[2]/div[4]/p')
    if results:
        savings_conditions = results[0].text.replace(' ...read less','')
    else:
        savings_conditions = 'No max rate conditions listed'    
    print(savings_conditions)
```